# React Native "Gradle build failed with exception"

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2s ok sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is due to incompatible gradle version so first go to
folder : android\gradle\wrapper
open he file gradle-wrapper.properties
and change

- **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip**

> to

- **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip**

---

simply we have to change the latest version
[image]